# Which kernel version should I pick for update

Tags: kernel, updates

Currently I am working on Ubuntu system. Here is my specifications

```
shark@ubuntu-00000:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.10
Release:    12.10
Codename:   quantal
shark@ubuntu-00000:~$ uname -r
3.5.0-43-generic
```

Now I am facing [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/522998) issue for USB 3.0 ports. I tried following solutions but that doesn't work

**Solution - 1**

- Create new files /etc/pm/config.d/00sleep_module and /etc/pm/config.d/unload_module
- And add SUSPEND_MODULES="xhci-hcd" into it.

**Solution - 2**

- blacklisting the xhci module.

Now I am trying to update my current kernel to latest one.

For latest kernel versions I referred [this link](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/?C=N;O=D).

So I have following two questions

1. Latest kernel version is `v3.17-utopic`and I am thinking, this kernel is for Ubuntu 14.10 (Utopic Unicorn) Beta 2. And I am using Ubuntu 12.10. So is it possible to use this kernel version.
2. If this is not possible then which kernel version should I use.

Thanks in advance. Just let me know any thing you need.

Comment: Questions regarding EOL releases are off-topic here. Upgrade to 14.04.

Answer (score 1):

You can use 3.17-Utopic at your own risk. I am using the same on Ubuntu 14.04.

**NOTE**: As per what I know, the kernels available in mainline are not completely tested. Once testing is done, it will be made available to you.

Best of Luck...

Answer (score 0):

12.10/Quantal is EOL - Dead! If you want to revive it, anything can work. I have been runnig kernel 3.12 on ubuntu 10.04 Lucid, and it works great.

My guess is that you can use any kernel, but the only way to find out is to try. If you are ready to compile yourself, then is kernel 3.4 still alive. It is the one closest to quantals original (3.5) and would eventually give you fewer problems.